# Dividing multiple columns by another columns giving NaN``

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1], "b": [2], "c": [3]})                                                                                                       

In [25]: df[["b", "c"]] / df["a"]                                                                                                                                
Out[25]: 
    b   c   0
0 NaN NaN NaN
```

I was expecting this to work, but it seems I do not understand what is going on behind the scenes. Why does this give `NaN`?

Answer (score 2):

You need `.divide(..., axis=0)`:

```py
>>> df[['b', 'c']].divide(df['a'], axis=0)
     b    c
0  2.0  3.0
```

See the doc for [`DataFrame.divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html). Another example to better illustrate the operation that takes place:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 10], 'b': [2, 20], 'c': [3, 30]}) 
>>> df[['b', 'c']].divide(df['a'], axis=0)
     b    c
0  2.0  3.0
1  2.0  3.0
```

Explanation: why do you get `NaN` in `df[['b', 'c']] / df['a']`?

That is because a term-by-term division is attempted, but first `pandas` tries to align the two terms so that the columns match the outer join of all columns. Conceptually, it's like if, on the numerator, a third column `0` was added, filled with NaN, corresponding to `df['a']` (a series without column name), and the denominator became a 3-column frame with the two first columns named `'b', 'c'` and filled with NaNs, and the third column `0` containing the series `df['a']`. Now the division can take place, term by term, and you get a frame full of NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df[["b", "c"]] / pd.concat([df['a'], df['a']]).set_axis(['b', 'c'])
```

Or (as Pierre D suggests):

```
df[["b", "c"]].div(df["a"], axis=0)
```

---

Output:

```
     b    c
0  2.0  3.0
```

---

Explanation:

Take the example:

```
df[["b", "c"]] / df['a'].set_axis(['b'])
```

which outputs:

```
     b   c
0  2.0 NaN
```

This indicates that `pandas` tries to match `d['a']` index with `df[["b", "c"]]` columns. Since there is no match, it takes `NaN`. To prevent `pandas` from trying such a match, we can use `axis=0`.

If we try

```
df[["b", "c"]] / df['a'].set_axis(['c'])
```

we get as we would expect (there is a match between the column name `c` of `df[["b", "c"]]` and the index `c` of `df['a']`):

```
    b    c
0 NaN  3.0
```

Given this explanation, it should be clear why

```
df[["b", "c"]] / pd.concat([df['a'], df['a']]).set_axis(['b', 'c'])
```

works!